# wget ignores files despite *? wildcard search

Tags: linux, wget, mediawiki, wiki

i run the following command:

`wget -np -c -r -v -l1 -nd -A "*,*multistream-index*,*pages-articles.xml.bz2,*pages-meta-current.xml.bz2,*abstract.xml.gz,*pages-logging.xml.gz,*stub-articles.xml.gz,*stub-meta-current.xml.gz,*stub-meta-history.xml" -R "*.7z,*multistream*.bz2,*pages-articles?*.bz2,*pages-meta-current?*.bz2,*abstract?*.xml.gz,*pages-logging?*.xml.gz,*stub-articles?*.xml.gz,*stub-meta-current?*.xml.gz,*stub-meta-history?*.xml.gz" "https://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/20210401/"`

however i can't find anywhere about the order of precedence for wget when there's an accept/reject conflict and which will take place if there is a conflict.

for some files on the server, there are duplicate data sets, for instance, there is `enwiki-20210401-pages-logging.xml.gz` and then there is a bunch of files `enwiki-20210401-pages-logging.xml{1-27}.gz` containing the same data.

i only want to download 1 copy of the data in the simplest form, so i only want to download `enwiki-20210401-pages-logging.xml.gz` and not the numbered equivalents. i also don't want multistream or .7z files.

there are exceptions to this rule, however, some files there is only numbered copies, and so i've detailed in the wget accept/reject list what i want to and don't want to download.

the problem is wget seems to be ignoring a majority of the files, and i don't know why. i think it may have something to do with the `?*` wildcard reject list. for some cases i want to ignore any files with at least one numbered character after the initial part of the filename, so rejecting `*pages-logging?*.xml.gz` should take care of this, but it doesn't, and rejects all the files, instead of accepting the single file.

what am i doing wrong?

p.s. i know i should be using the wikidump mirrors, however i want to get it working first with the main server, plus most of the mirrors don't work (and haven't for quite some time).

Comment: my work-around was to use `wget -np -c -r -v -l1 -nd -R "*.7z,*multistream*.bz2,*pages-articles1*.bz2,*pages-articles2*.bz2,*pages-articles3*.bz2,*pages-articles4*.bz2,*pages-articles5*.bz2,*pages-articles6*.bz2,*pages-articles7*.bz2,*pages-articles8*.bz2,*pages-articles9*.bz2,*pages-articles0*.bz2,*pages-meta-current1*.bz2,*pages-meta-current2*.bz2,*pages-meta-current3*.bz2,*pages-meta-current4*.bz2,..,*stub-meta-history0*.xml.gz" -A "*" "https://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/20210401"` however this is messy and took way longer than it should have. anyone know where to file a wget bug report?

Comment: there's no bug; i figured out why - it was because i had `-c` for continue, and because the mirror wasn't updated, i was continuing from an old previously saved file for the `index.html` resulting in some files being skipped - simply deleting all the `.html` pages and re-running it correctly downloads all specified files